# Volley request inside BroadcastReceiver not working

Tags: java, android, android-volley, android-broadcastreceiver

Ok I have the following class which is supposed to execute when the device is turned on. So in order to try it I make a cold boot on my emulated device. Turns out the request seems never to be called. How is that possible?

```
public class AlarmNotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    private RequestQueue mQueue;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        mQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        while(true){
            if(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())){


                JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, API.getDeviceTypes(), null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            Log.d("mytag","TEST"); //THIS IS NEVER BEING PRINTED!
                            processResponse(response);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.d("mytag", "Error de response");
                        error.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });

                mQueue.add(request);
                Log.d("mytag","OK IM HERE EVERYONE"); // THIS WORKS

            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(60000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: see https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts#effects-process-state

Comment: @pskink mm that's no really helping, I don't even know where to look at

Comment: I think you must put it inside `runOnUiThread(runnable)`.

Comment: just start a `Service` and do your `"long running background threads"` there (or use [goAsync()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver#goAsync()))

Answer (score 0):

I test and debug your code on a broadcast reciever with if(true) (just in case I could see what happen?) and I see this work fine without while statement.
and I think your problem is from your code , not from using volley in broadcast receiver.
don't forget to add this line to manifest:

```
<receiver android:name="com.app.test.AlarmNotificationReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.alarm.notifier" />//this should be unique string as action
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

and permission:
     uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"

run this code and look at Logcat, this work fine!(you can see response on LogCat after 10 second, and on your code after 1 minute)

```
public class AlarmNotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private RequestQueue mQueue;
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d("onrecieve", "on recieveeeeeeeeee");


    mQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);

    if (true) {
        String url = " http://www.mocky.io/v2/5b2734202e000010009e42c3";

        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    Log.d("mytag", response.toString()); //THIS IS NEVER BEING PRINTED!
                    String name = response.getString("name");
                    Toast.makeText(context, name + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.d("mytag", "Error de response");
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        mQueue.add(request);

        Log.d("mytag", "OK IM HERE EVERYONE"); // THIS WORKS

    }
    try {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

}

Comment: Do not forget to register receiver and use action in trigger broadcast receiver:Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction("com.example.alarm.notifier");
        sendBroadcast(intent);